# Solving a super-quadric equation

Tags: nonlinear-analysis

I have to solve the following scalar non-linear equation.
\begin{equation*}
\xi^{\frac{2}{\varepsilon}}+(\xi-k)^{\frac{2}{\varepsilon}}=1
\end{equation*}

with respect to $\xi\geq 0$. Here $\varepsilon>0$ and $k\in[0,1]$ are given parameters. So far I'm using the bisection method, and it works fine. However, I would like to know if it is possible to get a closed form solution in function of $\varepsilon,k$. This is possible in the simple case $k=0$, indeed we have
\begin{equation*}
2\,\xi^{\frac{2}{\varepsilon}}=1
\end{equation*}
and so
\begin{equation*}
\xi =\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}}
\end{equation*}
but what can we say if $k\neq0$? Another simple case is the one where $\varepsilon=2$, so that we have
\begin{equation*}
\xi+(\xi-k)=1
\end{equation*}
and so
\begin{equation*}
\xi = \frac{1+k}{2}
\end{equation*}

Comment: $\epsilon=1$ or any of a number of specific rationals would also provide "easy" solutions.  Presumably $\epsilon\to 0$, so perhaps a specific subsequence of integers $\frac 2{\epsilon}$ would give a meaningful result.